# Expecting a request param with a "XOR" validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple request call in a spring mvc controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SomeDTO getSth(@RequestParam("paramA") Integer paramA, @RequestParam("paramB") Integer paramB) {
    // ...
}
```

and I want to have either the paramA or the paramB otherwise a normal http response as it currently happens if I do not provide both parameters.

I know there is a required parameter available, but I do not see a way to connect both. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a very good solution, but the straightforward one seems to be normal, isn't it?

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSth(@RequestParam(value = "paramA", required = false) Integer paramA,
        @RequestParam(value = "paramB", required = false) Integer paramB) {
    if (paramA == null ^ paramB == null) {
        return "body";
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public static class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```